# Two bootstrap select-picker with different background colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

As i am using [silviomoreto.github.io](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select) for dropdownlist and I have two bootstrap select-picker as below:

```
<select class="selectpicker">
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
</select>

<select class="selectpicker2">
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<script>
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
  width: 'fit'
});
</script>

<script>
  $('.selectpicker2').selectpicker({
  width: 'fit'
});
</script>
```

i have tried with this css code:

```
button.btn.dropdown-toggle.btn-default{
height:4vh;
line-height:0.8em;
border-radius: 25px;
background: #72c285;
color:#fff;
}
```

above css applies to both selectpickers. I need to apply different styles for selectpickers. 
I am not able to give different background color for each. Is there any way to give?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Browse to button classes https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @MohnammadUsman. There is not enough information in your question.

Still, assuming that you are using "https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select" there is a simple css class that you use as explained here "https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#styling" using data-style attribute.

Create a css class:

```
    .btn-black {
       background-color: black;
    }

    <select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-primary btn-black">
      ...
    </select>
```

Comment: data-style="btn-primary" this will give green color. but i need black color as background.